# BroadCast Variables In Spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

Lets say i have the following code running on a cluster:

```
private def modifyDatasetFormat(data : String, mappings : Array[HashMap[String, Int]]) : Array[Tuple2[Tuple3[Int,Int,Int],Int]] = {

}

var  map = new HashMap[String,Int]()
map+=("hello" -> 2)

var mappings = new Array[HashMap[String, Int]])(1)
mappings(0)=map

val originalDataset = sc.textFile("/home/paourissi/Desktop/MyProject/nursery.1000.withID")
        val dataset = originalDataset.
            flatMap(data => modifyDatasetFormat(data, mappingsInMap)).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
```

Do i need to use broadcast for the value mappings or it is not needed?
Basically when do we use broadcast variables anyway? For efficiency?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, Broadcast variables are designed to be shared throughout a cluster and, at the same time have to be able to fit in memory on one machine.

Secondly, broadcast variables are immutable, so they cannot be changed later on (in case take a look at accumulators).

**Efficiency**:
Inside Spark, all the nodes in the cluster try to distribute the variable as quickly and efficiently as possible by downloading what they can, and uploading what they can. This makes them much faster than one node having to try and do everything and push the data to all nodes.

As referenced in the [Apache Spark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables) , broadcast variables are a great case for "static look up tables"

You may like this interesting post by [SparkTutorials](http://www.sparktutorials.net/spark-broadcast-variables---what-are-they-and-how-do-i-use-them)